Following and Count of State Changes Between Columns in Polars
I have a dataframe with multiple IDs and corresponding states. I want to analyze how the states have changed over time and present this information effectively.
Here is an example:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1, 2, 3],
    "T0": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "T1": ["B", "B", "A"],  
})

One aproach it's to "concat" the columns , and then do a value_counts() of the Change column
df = df.with_columns(
    (pl.col("T0") + " -> " + pl.col("T1")).alias("Change")
)

However, there might be a better approach to this, or even a built-in function that can achieve what I need more efficiently.
Current Output:
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ ID  ┆ T0  ┆ T1  ┆ Change │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ A   ┆ B   ┆ A -> B │
│ 2   ┆ B   ┆ B   ┆ B -> B │
│ 3   ┆ C   ┆ A   ┆ C -> A │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘

shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ Change ┆ count │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ u32   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ C -> A ┆ 1     │
│ B -> B ┆ 1     │
│ A -> B ┆ 1     │
└────────┴───────┘


What is the expected output?

I just added the output, my question its more the way of how to approach this problem

Depending on the exact structure of the output you need, you can use pl.DataFrame.group_by() and .len():
df.group_by("T0","T1").len("count")

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ T0  ┆ T1  ┆ count │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str ┆ u32   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ C   ┆ A   ┆ 1     │
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ 1     │
│ B   ┆ B   ┆ 1     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘

You can also concat columns afterwards if you want:
(
    df
    .group_by("T0","T1")
    .len("count")
    .select(
        Change = pl.col.T0 + ' -> ' + pl.col.T1,
        count = pl.col.count
    )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ Change ┆ count │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ u32   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ A -> B ┆ 1     │
│ B -> B ┆ 1     │
│ C -> A ┆ 1     │
└────────┴───────┘

If you want to use pl.Expr.value_counts(), you can first combine columns into pl.struct():
df.select(pl.struct("T0","T1").value_counts())

shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────┐
│ T0            │
│ ---           │
│ struct[2]     │
╞═══════════════╡
│ {{"A","B"},1} │
│ {{"C","A"},1} │
│ {{"B","B"},1} │
└───────────────┘

